# PHP: INSERT a header on Fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

Hi guys I know I am asking a common question but in my case I have the following code:

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['countRows']) && empty($_SESSION['countRows']))
    {
        $_SESSION['countRows'] = $_POST['countRows'];
    }

    $data = date("dmY");

    $filename = "EstrazioneParziale_del_" . $data;

    $estensione = ".csv";

    $fileOpen = fopen($filename.$estensione, "a") or die("Impossibile aprire il file");

    $arrayData = ['Operation','Nome Servizio','ID Servizio','S.O.','Patch Level','N° Apparati'];

    fputcsv($arrayData, array_keys($_POST['arrayFiltrato'][0]));

    foreach ($_POST['arrayFiltrato'] as $fields) {

        fputcsv($fileOpen, $fields);

    }

    fclose($file);
```

The first fputcsv doesn't insert an header to the csv file and I only can see the csv file will all the datas without the header (I use $arrayData to get the headers). Can somebody help me? Many thanks! :-)

Comment: You may want to check the arguments you've passed to `fputcsv()`

Comment: In fact I can see many places where you're confusing or mistyping variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to put the headers out doesn't use the right parameters, the first is the file handle and the second is the data.  So...

```
fputcsv($arrayData, array_keys($_POST['arrayFiltrato'][0]));
```

should be

```
fputcsv($fileOpen,$arrayData);
```

Also you probably want to open the file in write mode instead of append (otherwise your new content will be added to the end of the existing content)...

```
$fileOpen = fopen($filename.$estensione, "w") or die("Impossibile aprire il file");
```

Your close is using the wrong file handle as well...

```
fclose($file);
```

should be

```
fclose($fileOpen);
```

Comment: This should be flagged for closure as typo, not answered.

Comment: @miken32, IMHO a typo applies to some of the problems, but how can opening the file for append be a typo?

Comment: That wasn't what their question was about though. It was about why the header line wasn't being put into the file, and the reason was simply incorrect arguments being supplied to the function. It's unlikely to be of help to anyone in the future, which is the measure of whether or not these questions should be closed.

Comment: @miken32, if someone is opening the file to check if the header is there or not on the first line of the file, then appending the header to the end of the file will mean it will never appear there except on the first run.

Comment: Again, this is a red herring. Append mode will create the file if it doesn't exist, you're making assumptions about the OP's environment that aren't stated in the question.

Comment: @miken32, I'm not making any assumptions - if the file doesn't exist then as I stated it will work on the first run.  If the file already exists (which means I am covering all bases rather than assuming the file will never exist) then the header will be added to the end of the file.  So their first test run will work, their second will fail etc.